# Ruby and Rails Slow response using THIN on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, thin, rds

I deployed an ROR application on without using cache because in some API data was not update on API.
Simply use gem 'thin' in Gemfile
in my application i have more then 1000k to 2000k users and API response being slow day by day as user increase.
some time API Timeout in 30 second , no to much queries , simple single query per API, and Using RDS server for Mysql

This is became headache

Comment: how many process of thin are running means how many thin server is running ? Is it one or more ?

Comment: 3 server one is developer used by one developer and another is for QA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this issue through this

http://nerian.es/articles/2014/08/30/how-to-handle-concurrent-requests-in-rails/

Answer (score 1):

Run thin server as :-

```
thin start -s3 -p 3000 -e production
```

But make sure the ports 3000,3001 and 3002 are publicly open.

It will start three process of thin. It can by increased by changing `-s3` to `-s5` and it will start five process of thin.

To stop these process:-

```
thin stop -s3 -p 3000 -e production
```

Comment: i dont have the issue to start application on another port ,, my issue is response is very slow